# Is there any way to change(downgrade) a video that I have from 30 FPS to 25 FPS

Tags: python-3.x, video, frame-rate

I am doing a project which requires videos to be at 25FPS. Now the videos I have are at 30FPS. Is there any way I can change it to 25FPS?